# Referencing object from within another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, require

I am creating a view in backbone that accepts a collection I want to then render that view then use the collection to append another view to the orginal but I don't know how to reference the original view in the success function of the collection. When I try the following code I get undefined.

```
new GenreView().render(new PopVideosCollection());

define (['jquery','underscore','backbone'],function($,_,Backbone) {
GenreView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:"div",
    className:"sect",
    template: _.template($("#genreView").html()),
    render: function (collection)
    {
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        collection.fetch ({success:function (video)
            {
                console.log(video.toJSON());
                                    console.log(GenreView.el);
            },
        });
    },
});
return GenreView;
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the instance of GenreView from inside the callback. Something like this should get you there:

```
var context = this;
collection.fetch ({success:function (video){
  console.log(video.toJSON());
  console.log(context.el);
  }
});
```

However, you should re-think your approach a little.  It would be better to call fetch on your collection, and have the view subscribe the `reset` event of your collection.  Starting with your example code, that would look something like:

```
var GenreView = Backbone.View.extend({


  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "reset", this.appendSubView);
  },

  render: function() {
     this.model.fetch();
  },
  appendSubView : function(video){
     console.log(video.toJSON());
     console.log(this.el);
  }

});
```